# If statement string comparison

Tags: if-statement, ksh

What am I'm doing wrong over here?
The script by default enters this IF statement & displays the echo statement to exit.

```
#!/bin/ksh


server=$1
dbname=$2
IFS="
"
if [[ "${dbname}" != "abc_def_data" || "${dbname}" != "abc_def01_data" ]]; then
        echo "Msg: Triggers can only be applied to CMS_JAD:abc_def_data/abc_def01_data!"
        exit 0
fi
```

Comment: you never use $server, is that intentional?

Comment: The condition is always true.

Comment: i only copied a part of the code... $server will be used later in the script... @Daniele

Comment: I felt so... But my intentions are to check the parameter & exit if the name doesn't match any of the 2 names i mentioned... @Mithrandir

Comment: I guessed as much. :-)

Answer (score 1):

chaining of `!=` conditions requires some inversion of thinking.

I much prefer a clearer path to testing these conditions by using the `case ... esac` structure.

```
case "${dbname}" in 
   abc_def_data|abc_def01_data ) 
        #dbg echo "matched, but for real code replace with just a ':' char" 
        :
   ;; 
   * ) 
       echo "didn_t match any expected values for \$dbname"
       echo exit 1
   ;; 
esac
```

Note that as you're really trying to find the `*)` case, the actions for the `abc_def_data (etc)` match can be anything, but to just skip to the next section of code, you would only need the shell's null cmd `:` .

**Edit 1**

Note that I have `echo exit 1`, just so if you copy/paste this to a command line, your shell won't exit. In real code, remove the `echo` and expect the `exit` to work.

**Edit 2**

Also, note that the `|` char in the case match (`abc_def_data**|**abc_def01_data`) is essentially an `OR` (I think it is called something else in the "case match" context).

IHTH

Comment: for every "dbname", the script gets into the IF statement & exits. 
my intentions are, when the dbname is not equal to abc_def_data or abc_def01_data, the script has to print that echo statement & exit... if dbname is equal to any of them both, it should not EXIT & go to the next step.

Comment: yes, I read and understood your question at the top. Did you try replacing your `if ... fi` block with this `case ... esac` block? It should work as you describe. Note that you can extend the list of OK as "wide" as you want like `abc_def_data|abc_def01_data|bcd_def_data|bcd_def01_data|....` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you, by any chance, meant to write this?

```
if [[ "${dbname}" != "abc_def_data" && "${dbname}" != "abc_def01_data" ]]; then
        echo "Msg: Triggers can only be applied to CMS_JAD:abc_def_data/abc_def01_data!"
        exit 0
fi
```

Comment: i'm confused here... i want the script to EXIT if the dbname is not equal to either abc_def_data or abc_def01_data.

Comment: Because that what my need is. The script has a task to do & it needs to be applied to a particular set of "dbname"s.

Comment: The Script will now exit, if the value of ${dbname} is neither "abc_def_data", nor "abc_def01_data". What is the confusing part?

Comment: @MRKR : Mentally, we construct these problems as lists of ORs. but for Boolean logic, it has to be expressed as `&&`s . Turn on shell debugging/trace with `set -vx` and look at what happens on expanded variables on the lines preceded with `+`. To further understand, replace one of the tests with `true` and then change that to `false` and think about the rules of logic and how it all connects. The shell is working correctly ;-) Good luck.

Comment: for every "dbname", the script gets into the IF statement & exits. 
my intentions are, when the dbname is not equal to abc_def_data or abc_def01_data, the script has to print that echo statement & exit... if dbname is equal to any of them both, it should not EXIT & go to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

try this man, it should work just fine you should have seperated the conditions with "[ ]" and used -o instead of ||....
btw it worked for me fine...

```
server=$1
dbname=$2
IFS=""

if [ "${dbname}" != "abc_def_data" ] -o [ "${dbname}" != "abc_def01_data" ]
        then
        echo "Msg: Triggers can only be applied to CMS_JAD:abc_def_data/abc_def01_data!"
        exit 0
fi
```